# Mapping a value in a new table to an input in Python

Tags: python

I am a total beginner to Python so apologies if this is a basic question

I am trying to write a code which will iterate through an input table of hours that need to be fulfilled and subtract shifts which are created until there are no more hours left to allocate. So far I have an input file which I can read and this is as follows:

```
f=open('filepath','r')
f1=f.read()
print f1

6,9
7,10
8,10
9,10
10,6
```

which tells me at 6am I need 9 hours, and at 7am 10 hours etc.

I have created a shift as follows:

```
def shiftn():
        start=6
        length=4
            for start in range (start,start+length-1):
             print start,1
print shiftn()

6 1
7 1
8 1
9 1
```

Now I would like to subtract the shift from the input file, mapping the start times to each other so that I end up with the following:

```
6,8
7,9
8,9
9,9
10,6
```

where the shift that is starting at 6am and lasts for 4 hours has been subtracted from the initial required hours, leaving behind the remainder hours that need to be allocated to a shift.

How do I map the times to each other / do this?

Any help is much appreciated - I will continue to read Python for beginners!

Comment: You need to write the final result in the file?

Comment: You can create a dictionary of the file entries, and later use that dictionary for every item in your 'start' loop. Please note that if the "shift" is always 1, you might consider discarding the for-loop completely.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code, I will try to comment it so you understand, you must understand lists in order to understand how this works.

**Code:**

```
def readFile():
    f = open('sample.txt', 'r')
    f1 = f.read()
    # Each row of the file will be stored as a list inside the list 'rows'
    rows = [] 
    # split('delimiter') just splits the string 'f1', and return a list of strings. Read more in documentation
    for l in f1.split('\n'): 
        rows.append(l.split(',')) # Append each row (list) to 'rows'
    return rows

def shiftn():
    start = 6
    length = 4
    shifts = [] # Added to return a list of shifts values
    for start in range (start, start + length - 1):
        shifts.append([str(start), 1]) # Instead of print, append it to the list 'shifts'
    return shifts

def substract(rows, shifts): # Receive as parameters the result of readFile() and shiftn()
    new_rows = rows[:] # Make a copy of 'rows'
    for i in range(len(rows)):
        for shift in shifts: # Iterate over each shift
            if shift[0] == rows[i][0]: # If the first values matches
                new_rows[i][1] = int(rows[i][1]) - shift[1] # Substract and assign the value to the corresponding row in 'new_rows'
    return new_rows

print substract(readFile(), shiftn())
```

**Output:**

```
>>> [['6', 8], ['7', 9], ['8', 9], ['9', '10'], ['10', '6']]
```

PS: Your method `shiftn()`doesn't give the output you wanted, you may want to modify it.

Comment: Thanks! - have you got a suggestion of a better title so that others too can benefit from this answer?

Comment: Also, if I want my start to be at '7' or '8' I get an error - "IndexError: list index out of range". Know why this is?

Comment: To correct this error replace `shifts[i][1]` with `shift[1]`. See edit

Comment: Thanks - Feliz ano nuevo!